# Считывание unicode

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

Имеется адрес в котором хранится строка в UTF-16. Вопрос как ее нормально считать в массив char с помощью ReadProcessMemory?
Я пытался вот так:

```
char buffer[100];
ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)address, &buffer, 20, NULL);
cout << buffer;
```

Вместо слова "вероятно" мне выдавало вот такой набор символов "25@>OB=>".

Comment: Да, но выводите-то вы ее как ASCII...

Comment: Если это UTF-16 то считывать надо в массив `wchar_t` (на виндовс) и выводить wcout. На линукс считывать в массив char16_t и конвертировать в UTF-8, и только потом выводить в cout

Comment: Чтоб считать в wchar_t достаточно просто заменить char на wchar_t? Я пробовал так и через wcout ничего вообще не выводилось. Онлайн декодер определил кодировку как ASCII 8BIT => UTF 16LE.

Comment: Попробуйте WCHAR и swprintf вместо char и cout.